# Lifting morphism of smooth projective curves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

I'm wondering about the following question.

> Let $R$ be a complete DVR with residue field $k$. Let $f_k : X \to Y$
> be a finite, separable morphism of smooth projective curves over $k$.
> Suppose we are given a smooth lift $\mathcal Y/R$ of $Y$. Does there exist a smooth curve $\mathcal X/R$ lifting $X$ and a finite morphism $f : \mathcal X \to \mathcal Y$, which lifts $f_k$?

I know that the answer is positive by a more general result using patching theory (see Proposition 5.2 in [this survey paper](http://www.math.u-bordeaux1.fr/%7Eliu/articles/tokyo.ps) by Qing Liu). But actually, I would like to know, **whether the answer is "obvious"** for some reason. For example, is it possible to prove this, using the infinitesimal deformation theory?

The paper of Liu mentions also that this should be possible by infinitesimal deformation theory and refers to [SGA I](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0206203.pdf), III.5.6. But SGA I, III.5.6 discusses a situation, in which the lifts $\mathcal X$ and $\mathcal Y$ are given. In this situation, the obstruction to lifting $f_k$ lives in the first cohomology of the pullback of cotangent sheaf of $Y$ to $X$. Can this fact be somehow used?

Comment: The link to the survey paper doesn't work for me.

Comment: @AriyanJavanpeykar : it works for me. It's called "Reduction and lifting of finite covers of curves"

Comment: I see. It's a link to a ps file. Maybe that's why it didn't work.

Comment: Treating $X$ as a $Y$-scheme, the obstructions to deforming $X$ to a given deformation of $Y$ are controlled by the cotangent complex $L_{X/Y}$, in particular the obstruction lies in $\mathrm{Ext}^2(L_{X/Y}, \mathcal{O}_X)$. In the case of curves, $X\to Y$ is flat lci, so $L_{X/Y}$ is easy to compute.

Comment: Just to add one remark: of course this can be proved by infinitesimal deformation theory, but it is slightly more involved than it might first appear.  For instance, the Frobenius morphism obviously does *not* lift (once the genus is $>1$).  So the computation is not automatic (it uses the fact that $L_{X/Y}$ is equivalent to the complex of a torsion sheaf).